# pandas seriesの行方向への結合について

Tags: python, pandas

下記のコードにて、date, p　をヘッダーに行方向に結合したいのですがうまくいきません。
どのようにすればできますでしょうか？

尚、tickには日付情報がはいっており、str(t.year) + str(t.month)で年月情報を作っています。pは機械学習によって得られるスコアを想定しており、これ自体は単一の数字です。

結果が

date    20154.000000
f           0.666667
date    20155.000000
f           0.666667
dtype: float64

のようにでてしまいます。
がほしい形は↓です。

date    f
20154 0.666667
20155 0.666667

```
 a = pd.Series((int(str(t.year) + str(t.month)),f1),index=['date','f'])
 b = pd.Series((int(str(t.year) + str(t.month + 1)),f1),index=['date','f'])

 pd.concat([a,b], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

単純にこんなのでどうですか。

```
pd.DataFrame([a, b])
```

結果の件数が多い場合は、最初にカラム名だけを定義した空のDataFrameを作成して、

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','f'])
```

appendしていけばできます。

```
df = df.append(a, ignore_index=True)
```

また、Seriesを作成ぜずに直接辞書型でappendすることもできます。

```
df = df.append({'date':int(str(t.year) + str(t.month)), 'f':f1}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

pd.concat([a,b],axis=1).Tでもできると思います